# Using GCKMediaControlChannel's sendTextMessage method yields error

Tags: ios, google-cast, chromecast

With google cast iOS SDK, The GCKMediaControlChannel's sendTextMessage method is straightforward and it's hard to mis-use so I am guessing this may be a bug in the SDK ... hopefully someone will prove me wrong so I can get back to work!

Here's the code:

```
NSDictionary *messageDict = @{
                            @"message": @"blah",
                            @"num":[NSNumber numberWithInt:2]
                            };
  NSError *error;
  NSData *msgData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:messageDict
                                                      options:0
                                                        error:&error];
  NSString *message = @"" ;
  if (!msgData) {
    DDLogError(@"ERROR serializing message: %@", error);
    return NO ;
  } else {
    message = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:msgData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [self sendTextMessage:message] ;
  }
```

...the receiver produces this error when the message is received `[cast.receiver.mediaManager] Ignoring request, requestId is not an integer: undefined`

At first view it seems like GCKMediaControlChannel inherits directly its sendTextMessage method from the GCKCastChannel, failing to implement some of the messaging aspects specific to the media channel (in particular failing to wrap the message in a media-style envelope with the `requestId` and `mediaSessionID` attributes)

Has anybody else encountered this? Am I missing something? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

I followed the recommendation on the [ticket I created](https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=161), messaging to the receiver media app using a custom namespace using `GCKCastChannel` instead of he dedicated `GCKMediaControlChannel` to work around the issue. The ticket response confirms "don't use sendTextMessage directly with the GCKMediaControlChannel"

Comment: I have no idea how you interpreted the response in the ticket as "GCKMediaControlChannel is buggy", you were incorrectly using the Media Control channel, so the bug is in fact in your code not the SDK.

Comment: @AliNaddaf My code was following the API as [documented](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/ios/interface_g_c_k_cast_channel#a536d42cdfb9d56d9ed10c3f75c493985). If the SDK doesn't work as documented, either the SDK is buggy or the doc is.

Not trying to start a right-vs-wrong debate, I am happy enough if I helped the next developer getting stuck for candidly following the API doc

Comment: The Media Control Channel is a subclass and defines a particular namespace. Each namespace defines a spec for the messages that it can handle; Media Control Channel has its own spec and messages that it handles. If you write a TicTacToe Channel subclass, you would define a new namespace and a spec for the messages that it can handle; you cannot expect the same interpretation of text messages by different channels. Documentation says it sends a text message but leaves it open what that text message can be or how that will be handled/interpreted since that is up to the subclasses.

Comment: I understand how it works...yet can we agree that the fact that the sendTextMessage is unusable with the dedicated media channel & no word about it in the doc is confusing at best? Either way I rephrased my response

Comment: When you define a new namespace and a new channel, you define a protocol. "Sender" is only half of the story, the other half is the "Receiver": sender puts together a message and sends that to the receiver and based on the agreed protocol, receiver interprets the message. So sender is truly sending a text message but receiver will ignore or complain if does not match the agreed upon protocol. (see the rest in the next comment due to comment size limit)

Comment: That is what's happening here; the text message that you were sending does in fact get to the receiver but the Media Channel receiver doesn't accept since your message didn't follow the expected spec. If you were to send a message that was adhering to the Media Channel protocol, the receiver would have accepted it. That is why I said sendTextMessage() does send a message and documentation is correct. Also, thank you for updating your response, that looks good.